# ¿Como insertar una variable dentro de un resultado en mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Mi duda es esa. Por ejemplo, tengo dos schema, libros y categorías. Entonces desde la administración me gustaría saber cuantos libros tiene cada categoría.

```
return Category.find({}, async function( err, data ){

    const result = [];

    await data.map(d => {
        d.booktotal = 10;
        console.log( d );
    })



    /**
     * 
     */

    // return res.status(200).json({
    //  categories: result
    // });
});
```

Como ven obtengo las categorías e intento iterar cada categoría y agregar la variable `totalbook` con un valor "**10**" pero si le doy `console.log` a la variable `d` entonces este solo muestra el nombre de la categoría mas no muestra la variable `booktotal`. ¿Como inserto en un resultado una variable personalizada que contenga un valor estático o un resultado de otra consulta en mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

Primero buscas en la tabla Category.

`const categories = await Category.find({}).lean();`

El lean sirve para que te devuelva solo el objecto de las categorías, si no haces el lean te devuelve un objecto Mongoose.

Una vez tienes las categorías ya puedes añadir el valor que quieras.
Debería quedarte así el código:

```
const categories = await Category.find({}).lean();
const result = categories.map(category => {
    category.booktotal = 10;
    return category;
});
return res.status(200).json(result);
```